# positioning image in a box

Tags: css, html, position

My problem is that I can´t position two divs abreast. I want a white background box with the date in the right top corner. The image should be on the same height like the date.

Here´s my code:

```
#boxx {
background-color: white;
width: 768px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin-top: 30px;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 10pt;
}
#date{
text-align: right;
color: #d50a0a;
position: relative;
}

#image{
margin-left: 5px;
position: float;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

When I try it, the image is always one line beneath the date. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: set the postion of boxx to relative and the postion of date to absolute. then top and right 0 for date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of putting

```
position:float;
```

try with

```
float:left;
```

(or right as needed)